# How to convert dBm/MHz to dBm?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields, dimensional-analysis, unit-conversion

I wonder if we can convert dBm/MHz (eirp) to dBm?

For example:

What is the equivalent of -30 dBm/50MHz as dBm?

Edit 1: I wonder if power spectral density (dBm/MHz) can be expressed in dBm. In EN 302 065 ETSI standard, there are limits for power spectral density (see page 12) which are in dBm/MHz. I wonder if we can convert them to dBm. Or is this impossible and why?

Link to standard: https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_en/302000_302099/30206501/02.01.01_60/en_30206501v020101p.pdf

Comment: These are just units. What is the physics behind it? Probably you have to multiply with with a bandwidth or integrate over a frequency range. However, in order to provide a meaningful answer, you have to tell us what you try to do and not just stating the units.

Comment: Thank you, I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider an equivalent example:

The mass density of water is $\rho_m \approx 1kg/liter = 1000 kg/m^3$. We are able to calculate the mass of the volume $V$ of water, but in order to do so, we have to know the volume,
$$
M = \int \rho_m  dV = \rho_m V
$$
The second equation is true if the mass density is constant over the volume.

Just transferring mass density to mass is impossible. These are two different things. The same is true for the power spectral density. If you like to obtain the power within some frequency range $[f_1, f_2]$ you have to integrate the power spectral density across this frequency range.  Thus, you can take the given frequency limits from table 2 (see your linked document) and calculate the max power within each band. E.g.
\begin{align}
%max\{PSD(f \le 1.6GHz)\} &\le -90dBm/MHz
%\\
%\Rightarrow 
\textrm{max. power in the range [0, 1.6]GHz} &: -90dBm/MHz  \cdot (1.6 - 0)GHz = \ldots 
\\
\textrm{max. power in the range [1.6, 2.7]GHz} &: -85dBm/MHz  \cdot (2.7-1.6)GHz = \ldots \\
\ldots
\end{align}